# How to set default value on LightSwitch 2013 table?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm building a project on LightSwitch 2013 - Visual Studio 2013.
I have a data table on the screen that has 5 rows.
I want that the first row will be selected by default when the user navigate to that screen.

I know how to do that with screen.DataTable.selectedItem,
the problem is that when the user navigate to the screen it choose the right line on the table but the user can't see that it has been chosen (the user doesn't see the blue background on the line) - to solve that i used with setTimeout with a delay of 500 ! it's a lot !

By the way, it's on the client side --> Javascript.

how do i fix this problem without setTimeout??

Thanks.